# GSM incoming bytes from UART not complete

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I have used AT commands to read incoming bytes from serial buffer from SIM900A but I cannot get the complete message using the code below:

```cpp
while(ss.available()>0)
{
 inChar=ss.read();
 inString+=inChar;
}

Serial.println("Received messaged: ");
Serial.println(inString);

inString="";
```

However this one below works:

```cpp
if(ss.available()>0)
{
  inString=ss.readString();
}

Serial.println("Received messaged: ");
Serial.println(inString);

inString="";
```

I wonder what is the difference?

Comment: How big is `inString`? Could you please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The data arrive over serial very slow compared to MCU speed. In the first snippet you stop reading at first gap between bytes (available is 0). In the second snippet the function `readString` will wait for the next byte until a second (at default).